# How do I apply CSS transitions (e.g. fade-ins) to a list of items in React so their animations are sequenced one after the other on render?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations, css-transitions

I've been searching Stack Overflow and the whole internet for this and couldn't find the right answer, so sorry if this is a duplicate question.

I've got a list:

[image]

How do I apply CSS transition to the list of elements, one by one, only on page load in React?

I was able to use `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`, and it works fine, but it applies the transition to the entire list at the same time.

### React:

```
<ul className="item-list">
  <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="fade" transitionAppear={true}
    transitionAppearTimeout={2000}>
    {props.items.map((item, i) => (<li><someComponent/></li>)}
  </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
</ul>
...
```

### CSS:

```css
.fade-appear{
  opacity: 0;    
}
.fade-appear-active{
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-out;    
}
```

As I previously mentioned, I need to apply the above transition to the list of items one after another.

Comment: Maybe you can wrap each item into a ReactCSSTransitionGroup and use the index to set different AppearTimeout values? like `transitionAppeartimeout={2000 + 500*i}`

Comment: @arieljuod *transitionAppeartimeout* determines the transition duration not the delay before transition i guess

Comment: Not sure if this affects the issue you're having, but I think you may be using an old implementation of CSSTransitionGroup. Per the react docs, this is now part of https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/tree/v1-stable which has a slightly different syntax. Also you should be aware that as-is, this is injecting a `<span>` as a direct child of `<ul>` which is not valid. You can specify a `component` and `className` attribute on `< ReactCSSTransitionGroup>` and effectively combine it with the `<ul className="item-list">` so they are one and the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the effect is usually referred to as “staggered,” “cascading,” or “sequenced.”

Rather than using `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`, you could do this mostly with CSS.

First, I'd animate your cards using [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) property and [`@keyframes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) instead of [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) property. So to start, you could add something like this to your CSS:

### CSS

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

### Javascript

The crux of the solution is to set an [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) CSS style on each list item, and use the item index as a multiplier for a specified `delay` value.

I started by creating an array of objects called `items`, where each object contains a `title` and a `text` field (mainly just needed an array to map for the example).

I also created a couple of constants for abstracting the two numerical values for the animation, `duration` and `delay` (note we're only doing math with `delay` in the example to follow, but it looked cleaner to me to pull out `duration` as well):

```js
const duration = 1000; // ms
const delay = 500; // ms
```

Made a template that returns a formatted string to be used as the value of each transition element's [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) CSS property:

```js
const animStr = (i) => `fadeIn ${duration}ms ease-out ${delay * i}ms forwards`;
```

Mapping the data during render time, and setting the CSS `animation` style based on the index value (`i`) via `animStr`:

```
{items.map((item, i) => (
  <li key={i} style={{ animation: animStr(i) }}>
    <SomeComponent item={item} />
  </li>
))}
```

The animation will become active as soon as that element is injected into the DOM (as per the CSS animation spec). Syntax is based on the [css animation shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation). Note that the default behavior for the animation is to run once. Adding [`forwards`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) to the rule causes the animation to retain the properties of the last keyframe when it stops (fully visible).

---

Edit: Personally, I think it looks better to start the delay index at `1` instead of `0`, so you could set your `animation` value to this:

```css
`fadeIn ${duration}ms ease-out ${delay * (i + 1)}ms forwards`
```

---

### Working CodeSandbox

Here's a [working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-khayyam-iicb7?file=/src/App.js).

---

### Screen Recording

This is what the above code looks like in action. It's a screen recording of the page being reloaded on CodeSandbox.

[image]

Comment: FYI when you visit the codesandbox, if you want to test the animation repeatedly, you can use the little refresh icon in the embedded browser in the output UI (rather than refreshing the actual page)

Comment: Also if you wanted to define a timing function (like `ease` or a custom `cubic-bezier` curve) then you could add that value between the `duration` and `delay` values in the `animation` rule.

Comment: Edit: went ahead and added `ease-out` to the animation rule.

Comment: Edit: updated the animated GIF to demonstrate the `delay * (i + 1)` animation change I just made to the code.

Comment: What if I want run the animation only once and on app startup?

Comment: As-is, it only animates once when the list items are first injected to the DOM, which if it's the first thing that renders in the app, will effectively animate only once and on startup. Do the list items get destroyed and then injected again later? And if so, are you trying to avoid animations for any injection after the initial one?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this would be to use a library. Both of the following libraries can achieve this effect with some added features:

[react-drizzle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-drizzle)

[react-awesome-reveal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-awesome-reveal)

Answer (score 1):

If you're committed to keeping `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` then you could probably just add a custom `transition-delay` property on each item, similar to the solution in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68946048/how-to-apply-css-transition-on-a-list-items-one-after-another-using-reactjs/68947030#68946347).

```js
const delay = 500;
```

And do something like this:

```js
{props.items.map((item, i) => (
  <li style={{ transitionDelay: `${delay * i}ms` }}>
    <SomeComponent item={item} />
  </li>
)}
```